# Javascript function keep asking for argument

Tags: javascript

First I made function:

```
function createComment(template) {
 let emoji = document.getElementById("emojis").value;
 let comment = template.replace(/p/g, emoji)
 document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = "kok" ;
```

}

and in HTML button : `<button type="button" onclick="createComment()">Go</button>`

but, I wanted to remove `template` argument from function because button didn't work so I just reduced JS function to :

```
function createComment() {
//let emoji = document.getElementById("emojis").value;
//let comment = template.replace(/p/g, emoji)
document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = "kok" ;
```

}

but even now developer tools report error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createComment' on 'Document': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.`

If I change function name to anything to anything else like from `createComment` to `createCommentS` and in `button` too it works. For some reason it just keeps on hanging of original function argument and it's stubborn doesnt wanna give up on asking argument. Why?

Comment: Where are you calling the function? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @D.Pardal Can see it being called in onclick of button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the function to something else because it is probably being shadowed by [`document.createComment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createComment)

Comment: I did. Is there any way to get rid of that shadowing?

Comment: Not really unless you didn't use `onclick` in the `document`. If it is called as a function in window scope may not collide like in `addEventListener` but I'm not 100% sure